# Substring leaves a curly brace at the end with no escaped braces

Tags: c#, string

I have a `string` in C# that is converted from a `decimal` value using `String.Format()` and rounds the number to 2 decimal places:

`string result = "some stuff $" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", decValue);`

So, the `result` variable will look something like: `some stuff $4.99`

The `result` variable is actually a larger `string` with the `decimal` value appended to the end of it. So, when I get the actual `decimal` value back from the string, I'll do something like this:

```
string str = result;
str = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf("$")+1);
decimal dec = decimal.Parse(str);
```

The problem is, the `Substring()` method is leaving a literal curly brace `}` on the end of the returned substring, so I can't actually parse it as a decimal:

`4.99}`

I can get rid of the brace manually, but I don't see why I should have to as it makes no sense as to why `Substring()` is actually leaving the brace hanging on the end there.

Comment: "the result variable is actually a larger string with the decimal value appended to the end of it." Print `str` before calling `substring` to see what't the issue.

Comment: You should provide the minimal code which cause this issue. In your example the `result` doesn't contain curly brace.

Comment: How `decValue` get the value?

Comment: Please try to provide the code which gives the value to  'decValue'  as the code part given by you alone cannot provide a brace

Comment: If I had to _guess_, since you didn't copy/paste your _actual_ `result` assignment, I'd say you might have a typo in your _actual_ code. I would guess that you have an extra curly brace: `string result = "some stuff $" + String.Format("{0:0.00}}", decValue);` (note the extra curly brace after "0.00") Also, I wouldn't use `String.Format` _just_ to use curly brace notation. You can just have: `"someStuff $" + decValue.ToString("0.00")` or if you wish, use `String.Format` around the whole thing: `String.Format("someStuff ${0:0.00}", decValue);`

Comment: Thank you - I finally got a chance to look at this program again and that wasn't the issue, but I did find the actual issue as noted in my answer to the question. I changed the formatting in the ToString() method as you suggested though, as it's much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments. I actually figured out the issue and it was entirely different. I am using a ListView and I was getting a `list.SelectedItems[0].ToString()` value. This value itself returned something like: `ListViewItem: {Item Here}` which explained the curly brace. I did however change the formatting with `ToString("0.00")` as Chris suggested.